# Am receiving this error:

Tags: php, html, parsing, syntax

Am receiving this error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp\www\test\seta2.php on line 16

wer am i going wrong

```
            <html>
            <head>
            <title>My First PHP Page</title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <?php
            $grting = "Wellcome to php";
            echo "Hello World! ";
            echo "Hello World! ";
            echo "Hello World! ";
            echo "Hello World! ";
            echo "Hello World! ";
            echo ($grting)


            $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
             if (!$con)
               {
               die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
               }
            ?>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Perhaps try looking at the line that is mentioned in the error before asking others for help?

Comment: Yes, im going out on a whim here, but perhaps there *is* an error on line 16?????

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a semi-colon:

```
echo ($grting)
```

should be

```
echo ($grting);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `;` here

```
echo ($grting);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no semicolon at the end of `echo ($grting)`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `;` after `echo ($grting)`. The parentheses are unnecessary, and probably hid the cause of the error from you.